# Beamer notes printed in the same page right under each bullet points

Tags: beamer

I understand that Beamer can print notes in a separate page. It also has the capability of displaying the notes in the computer screen while displaying the content of the frame in the projected screen. But my need is a little different. I usually write voluminous notes with each slide and I would like to see them before or after each of bullet points in the slide. After incorporating notes in such a way, I would like to have two versions of the slide. One version will be without the notes which will be beamed in the screen. I would like to keep the other version with all the notes printed and notes must have to be in the same page where the contents are.

The reason I want this is that when the first bullet in a new frame starts, I would just like to take a glance in my printed presentation slide and get an idea on how I am planning to present the content of that bullet point. With the notes separated from the content, it becomes quite difficult to track down which bullet point is referred to which note. If notes are right below or above the bullet points in a frame, then only those can be easily related.

I understand Beamer prints the notes in a different page so that contents remain intact. But for me that does not work. I would like to have the notes in the same page as the content. I understand it may increase the size of the frame which may not contain in the same page. In that I would like Beamer to automatically switch the content of a frame into the next frame whenever it is required. Then when I compile the slides with notes option switched off, the frames should shrink back to original number and size.

I don't know whether Beamer has this capability at all, if not please feel free to suggest other alternatives in TeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this fulfil your needs? If you remove `handout` from the document class options, you will get a version without the note.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item bla 
            \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}}           
            \item blub
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

for automatic framebreaks you can use the `allowframebreak` option. But this won't work together with automatic uncovering of the items

```
\documentclass[
handout
]{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item bla 
            \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}}      

                        \item bla 
                        \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}} 

                        \item bla 
                        \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}} 

                        \item bla 
                        \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}} 

                        \item bla 
                        \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}}  

                        \item bla 
                        \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}} 

                        \item bla 
                        \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}} 

                        \item bla 
                        \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}}                       
                        \item bla 
                        \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}} 

                        \item bla 
                        \mode<handout>{\newline\textcolor{red}{notetext}} 


            \item blub
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to automatically move part of the content of a slide to a new slide when notes are added.  Also  when compiled with the handout turned off, those extra slides should go away.

Comment: @RushadFaridi See the edit.